# PHP - Mysqli query is returning half string

Tags: php

I am trying to return an access token but for some reason, when I print it on the page (to debug), I am getting a partial access token from MySql. Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM queue";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $at = $row['access_token'];
    echo $at;
}
```

For whatever reason, `$at` is almost half as long as it should be.

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: what is access_token data type

Comment: Out of desperation, Ive tried varchar(999) and longtext

Comment: how large is access_token, and what is the lenght of truncated access token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `mysqli/PDO` truncates your string , most likely it is due to `varChar` Type.

You have 2 option either change `dataType` to `TEXT` to avoid 255 Character limit or convert that field to a text in the query:

```
SELECT CAST (access_token AS TEXT) AS access_token FROM queue
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your access_token is stored in full length in your database? Code seems fine, so probably your problem is with your database.

If your access_token data type is VARCHAR then make sure you have set correct length for it.

Comment: Yes, the full length token is sitting safely in the database.

Comment: Have you tried to use mysqli_error to check if there are errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting access_token to bigint if the access token is a large integer?

Comment: The access_token is both letters and numbers. So integer wont work, right?